# How to run a python program as if from command line in a C++ project

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, juce

I'm writng a C++ audio plug-in that uses this python neural network to analyse the sentiment of the image: https://github.com/fabiocarrara/visual-sentiment-analysis. When using the python script as directed in the read.me from my terminal it runs fine and produces the right output.

However, I cant get it to work when embedded in my C++ program using the python/C API (I don't really undertsand the API) so how would I do this/ is there a different or easier way to achieve this?

The command enteretd into a terminal opened at the project directory is:
"python predict.py images_list.txt --model vgg19_finetuned_all --batch-size 64 > predictions.csv"
and the goal is to intialize a python environment embedded in C++ that will do the same as running that command.

I am struggling with configuring the python interpreter using the python C API to enter the arguments

The plug-in is written in C++ with JUCE on a mac

Comment: "I cannot get it to work" is not exactly something we can help you with. What (code) did you try? What was the result? How was it insufficient?

Comment: Sorry this post wes more meant to ask on advice using the python C api as i dont understand it, specifically configuring/preconfiguring the environemnt with arguments to run with the file. I have edited the post now wiht more information

Comment: Is there a reason or perceived benefit you see from embedding python instead of just shelling out with the `system(...)` function? That is by far the easiest approach.

Comment: I agree that is the simplest (and probably preferable) way but when using the `system(...)` function call it returns the error of not being able to find imported modules in the python script despite having them installed on my machine. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: When in doubt print the contents of `sys.path` in both cases. I'm guessing a `virtualenv` is involved somehow, or you need to change working directories first.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ChildProcess class in JUCE.

It allows you to create a subprocess, which you can use to execute OS CLI Commands. You can also run this process asynchronously, so it won't block the GUI thread.

https://docs.juce.com/master/classChildProcess.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34600123)